# GCS client library (python) "gzip" breaks direct download

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

With GCS client library (python) if I create an object with gzip support it breaks direct download link, server just return empty response or sometimes "service unavailable". But it I remove "gzip" from Content-Encoding then it works fine. Here is my code and I'm using it from GAE:

```
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename, 
                        'w',
                        content_type='application/json',
                        options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read',
                             'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
                             'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=0'}, 
                        retry_params=write_retry_params)
```

Is there any workaround to support gzip with public-read? has anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Are you writing valid gzip data? Can you download the object using gsutil?

Comment: @jterrace I'm writing plain text data and my understanding is GCS will compress based on header information, no?

Comment: No, the Content-Encoding is metadata only. If you specify Content-Encoding gzip, you need to also supply gzipped content.

Comment: @jterrace Thanks for your comment, I will try with manual compression.